# Jmeter- Regular expression extractor-Remove double quotes

Tags: jmeter

I have the response below from a request:

```
"wd:Report_Entry" : [ {
        "wd:referenceID" : "INTEGRATION_EVENT-6-60442",
        "wd:Integration_System" : {
            "@wd:Descriptor" : "Worker details for Mule Soft - CC",
            "wd:ID" : [ {
                "@wd:type" : "WID",
                "$" : "04ce61fbe864013e1fa5b4ce1a9c6e17"
            }, {
                "@wd:type" : "Integration_System_ID",
                "$" : "Worker_Details_MuleSoft_CC"
            } ]
        },
        "wd:Created_Moment" : "2018-09-06T00:31:14.836-07:00"
    }, {
        "wd:referenceID" : "INTEGRATION_EVENT-6-60441",
        "wd:Integration_System" : {
            "@wd:Descriptor" : "Worker details for Mule Soft - CC",
            "wd:ID" : [ {
                "@wd:type" : "WID",
                "$" : "04ce61fbe864013e1fa5b4ce1a9c6e17"
            }, {
                "@wd:type" : "Integration_System_ID",
                "$" : "Worker_Details_MuleSoft_CC"
            } ]
        },
        "wd:Created_Moment" : "2018-09-06T00:28:34.301-07:00"
    }
```

I need to capture `wd:referenceID` value (multiple values), for example `INTEGRATION_EVENT-6-60441` and pass it to the next request.

I have tried Regular expression `"wd:referenceID" : (.*?)",`. Its capturing `"INTEGRATION_EVENT-6-60441"` with double quotes. I would require the `INTEGRATION_EVENT-6-60441` (without double quote) and need to loop number of times of the Reference ID for the next request).

Answer (score 1):

Check the below Regular Expression

[image]

Below you can see the output that all the values are getting retrieve without double quotes.
[image]
Now, you can get the values via var_referenceID_1,var_referenceID_2 etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your regular expression with quotation marks like:

```
"wd:referenceID" : (.*?)",
```

This way the quotation marks will not be included into the group and you will get "clean" value:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor quotation marks]

---

One more thing to consider: your response is utterly like to be a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), if so - using regular expressions is not the best idea. JMeter provides [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries to fetch "interesting" parts of the response, in your case the relevant JSON Path expression would be:

```
$..wd:referenceID
```

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor]